# IntelliJIdea: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentArtifactsResult'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When configuring project with Gradle I recieve:

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentArtifactsResult'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

I have same error when using either local gradle distribution option: C:/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-1.12-bin/gradle-1.12

or gradle 'wrapper' task configuration file with url: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip.

Also tried to delete .gradle folder and configure project again and use default gradle wrapper.
So, there're many examples to solve it using Android Studio but unfortunatelly none for IDEA. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

EDIT: So, it was only part of trables with Gradle. The true problem was in encache library version. It was so in my gradle.build:

```
module: "ehcache", version: "2.10.4"
```

The decision was in changing Gradle version to 4.7 and removing encache version like this:

```
module: "ehcache"
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Doc says that the Interface [ComponentArtifactsResult](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/ComponentArtifactsResult.html) exists since `2.0` Gradle version. You should choose more recent Gradle version.

Comment: Facing the same issue, Did you get any workaround/fix for the same ?